# Execute SQL statement on page load up

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I execute an SQL statement from when I open up the webpage. At the moment, I am using a submit button.
I tried using Ajax but have limited knowledge.

Thanks

Here is my PHP after the select button has been pressed

```
<?php 
                        if (isset($_POST['info'])){
                        $selectOption = $_POST['info'];

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `REQUESTS` ORDER BY $selectOption"; 
                        $result = $db->query($query);
```

Comment: Where is that Ajax that you tried? And where does this PHP code actually output something?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "status.php",
  data: "{info}"
}).don(function (msg)) {
 alert("saved" + msg);
});

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code. A multi-line chunk of code in comments is generally unreadable. Please also add the current result you got (including any error messaged you get from PHP or in the console of the browser), and the result you expected to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your code out of the if statement. You are saying if something is inside (i.e. text inside the input element ) the input element with an id of info.

Remove the if statement and your code will work.

Comment: What do you mean 'inside'? This answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have you never programmed in PHP before. Yes this answer does make sense. Read it again. Don't down vote if you don't know PHP.

Comment: *PHP gold badge owner ;)  Have you seen the question's code? It takes a value from the $_POST array. That value is some value that should be posted. To make sure the code doesn't fail, it's common practice to check if that value is set in the $_POSTS array. So again, your answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't see you replying to his post. Don't down vote just put a better answer. Because while mine "doesn't make sense" it still works.

Comment: You're not obliged to counter a downvote with an answer as you may have read in [the 2 minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I can't answer the question because it doesn't contain enough information. Instead I downvoted the question, voted to close it, and added a comment explaining what I think is missing. But just because I don't answer this question doesn't mean I can't judge your answer. And I can: this code doesn't work,  because if the `if` would be the cause, then removing it would cause the next line to fail, since you're trying to read the non-existing array index there.